# Android MediaPlayer stops playing after some time

Tags: android, media-player, playback

Having small game to play short sound after onclick ImageButton. But after touching 10times MediaPlayer stop playing sounds on short time. After sometime it play sound again. When I look to LogCat console it show error: `E/MediaPlayer(19584): error (1, -2147483648)`.

Please can you show me the way to find sollution to solve this  problem ? Why MediaPlayer gives me error ?

I use this part of code to play Sound:

```
public void playAudio () {
    try {
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.trefa);
    mediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
    mediaPlayer.start();
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {

            }
    });
    } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("beep", "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    }
```

Comment: "But after touching 10times MediaPlayer stop playing sounds on short time" does it play normally with one touch?

Comment: With one touch ok, when I press more times (quickly or slowly) it is ok. Then after some clicks (approx 10 - not exactly) sound is mutted. Then after sometime (about 10-15 sec) sound play again.

Comment: For short audio files like we use in games. Sound pool class is the best choice. MediaPlayer is costly in terms of processing. If possible move to SoundPool as early as posible.

Answer (score 5):

The sollution for me is really to use SoundPool (not MediaPlayer). I have replaced my MediaPlayer with SoundPool from this tutorial: http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-programming-tutorials/sound-pool-example-in-android-development  and everything is ok.