# android media player stops playing after some minutes

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have an issue with Media player always stopping randomly after some few mins, most times, when the phone sleeps and you touch it again, the video hangs and stops playing.

I have tried many solutions here on stackoverflow, none worked. I'm almost pulling my hair out !!!

I've tried this answer

[Android MediaPlayer stops playing after some time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19566450/android-mediaplayer-stops-playing-after-some-time)

[MediaPlayer randomly stops on Android 4.4 (19)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19918118/mediaplayer-randomly-stops-on-android-4-4-19)

[How to prevent mediaplayer to stop when screen goes off?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13096715/how-to-prevent-mediaplayer-to-stop-when-screen-goes-off)

and many more answers, they all didn't work

This is my code below

```
public class MainActivity {

    MediaPlayer mp;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.my_webm_video);
mp.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
        playVideo();

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.my_webm_video);
        mp.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
        playVideo();
    }

    public void playVideo(){

        SurfaceView sv = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
        SurfaceHolder holder = sv.getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback(){
            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) { }

            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
               mp.setDisplay(holder);
               mp.start();
               mp.setLooping(true);
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

            }

        });
    }


}
```

This is my XML layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, so i finally solved the problem. Incase any one else run into this issue

in onCreate i checked if the video was already playing, to make sure it isn't called to re-play each time.

```
int firstPlayed = 0;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.my_webm_video);
        mp.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
        if(!mp.isPlaying()) {
            firstPlayed = 1;
            playVideo();
        }
}
```

I checked in onResume incase the user navigates out of the activity and goes back, Which makes the video screen turn black.

```
public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
         if(!mp.isPlaying() && firstPlayed == 0) {
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.my_webm_video);
            mp.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
            playVideo();
        }
        firstPlayed = 0;
}
```

And then i noticed that i needed a firstPlayed check to be sure.