# MediaPlayer: error (-19, 0)

Tags: android

I tried all the solutions provided in this site & still i am getting this error.Don't know why it happen! please help me.

Here my code.

```
    MediaPlayer  mediaPlayer; 
     mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.square);

                mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(MainActivity.this);
                mediaPlayer.start();

     mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            mWinMusic[blocks].release();
                        }
                    });



    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {

    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.square);

          mp.start();
            return true;



}
```

Comment: can you please share what is the exception

Comment: Is it illegalStateException?

Comment: E/MediaPlayer: Error (-19,0)
 E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set

Comment: Don't care about this "Exception".  if its not actually crashing your app. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20087804/should-have-subtitle-controller-already-set-mediaplayer-error-android

Comment: what about E/MediaPlayer:Error(-19,0) still its not playing any audio sir

Comment: Then you are obviously doing the wrong thing

Comment: See my old issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37343910/android-media-player-stops-playing-after-some-minutes/37350831#37350831 , if you use that source code and it doesn't work. then something is wrong with your Media file

Comment: @MahaMrityunjayaSaraswati check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Create player like this and add `mediaPlayer.prepare();` and when ready then start in `onPrepared()`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.square);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                }
            });
            mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Some problem ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return false;
                }
            });


            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "track completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //mWinMusic[blocks].release();
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Some problem " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code but raising null exception all times.

Comment: @MahaMrityunjayaSaraswati can you post your log here i want to have look or snapshot of it?

Comment: E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
 E/MediaPlayer: prepareAsync called in state 8
 E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set

Comment: Just now it produces illegalStateException

Comment: can you send me the media file i will try at my end at https://www.facebook.com/sohail.bsse